# keydown event not received when assigned to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn JS by following [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-dom-manipulation-and-events), in which they recommended finishing a tutorial from this Github [(JavaScript30)](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/), the first one involves triggering a highlight transition whenever a certain box is clicked or the corresponding key is pressed down.

I tried coding it myself first but found out that I'm not receiving the `keydown` event ever but receiving the click event normally, after reviewing the solution I found that he's assigning the event to window rather than the box itself.

why isn't my box receiving the keydown event and why should I assign that to window ?

```js
function togglePlaying(btn) {
  console.log(btn);
  btn.target.classList.toggle('playing');
};
document.querySelectorAll(".key").forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  key.addEventListener('keydown', togglePlaying);
  key.addEventListener('click', togglePlaying);
});
//window.addEventListener('keydown',togglePlaying);
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url('./background.jpg') bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://fav.farm/" />
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Elements which cannot be focused do not receive keyboard events (such as keydown). You can either add a tab index to the div to allow for it to catch keyboard events, or attach to the window (which does support keyboard events). Here is a fiddle with the tab indexes added, you should see it working https://jsfiddle.net/danieljoeblack/s42gtp5u/5/

Comment: I would recommending adding it to window instead of a specific div. The div will need to be focused on to receive the keyboard events.

Comment: I got what you mean by making it focusable after I read documentation for tabindex, but I don't understand what do you mean by "attach to the window", can you give an example or a some site to explain it ?

Comment: @OmarShawky by 'attach to the window' I mean what you have done in your example in the commented out line (`window.addEventListener('keydown',togglePlaying);`). Since window supports keyboard events and is a parent of all other elements, the `togglePlaying` function will be called any time any key is pressed, regardless of where the user is currently focused. Check the answer from Quentin, he explains how this could be done, and includes a general pattern you can follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a hashmap of the valid keys which are allowed to be pressed according to the structure of the divs.  Then in window keydown listener, if the key pressed was one of those keys, activate its div.

```js
function togglePlaying(btn) {
  //console.log(btn);
  btn.target.classList.toggle('playing');
};
document.querySelectorAll(".key").forEach((key) => {
  key.addEventListener('click', togglePlaying);
});

const btns = Object.fromEntries(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".keys .key")].map(k => 
    [k.querySelector("kbd").innerText.toLowerCase(), k]
  )
);

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  let validBtn = btns[e.key.toLowerCase()];
  if (validBtn) {
    validBtn.classList.toggle('playing')
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url('./background.jpg') bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://fav.farm/" />
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Key Events start at the element which has the focus and bubble up the DOM from there.

The `div` elements aren't (and don't contain any) `input` elements, elements with a `tabindex` or anything else what would allow them to hold the focus.

What's more, your design implies that it matters *which* key is pressed while *looking at the page*, not that *any* key can be pressed while the focus is on a particular element.

Binding the keydown listener to the `window` will capture any keydown event anywhere in the page. You can then use the [`key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) of the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) to determine which key was pressed and use that information to search the DOM for the element you want to toggle the class on.